# running an alarm based on a specific SMS while the mobile is turned off

Tags: android, sms, alarm

Actually, it is not one question, I have the following inquiries:
- do our smartphones receive SMSs while mobile is off?
- can we develop the android app that runs even the mobile is turned off?

I'm thinking about the emergency program, with the following scenario:
when a mobile receives SMS from a known sender (specific number) the mobile runs alarm and I need it to be working even I turn my mobile off.

Answer (score 1):

> do our smartphones receive SMSs while mobile is off ?

No, your phone is not connected to your carrier when it is off, so messages are not received.

> can we develop android app that run even the mobile is turned off ?

No, some phones have alarm capability when off, but you can't develop an app that would run when the phone is off.

> scenario: [...] I need it to be working even I turn my mobile off.

I believe this to be impossible at this time.